# Render a table with a json array in Reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, axios

I need to display the below jsonArray on a page in React.

```
[{
    "machine1": [{

            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Names": "mysql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        },
        {
            "Image": "kafka:latest",
            "Names": "kafka",
            "Status": "Up 15 hours"
        },
        {
            "Image": "postgresql:latest",
            "Names": "postgresql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "machine2": [{
            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Names": "mysql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        },
        {
            "Image": "elasticsearch:latest",
            "Names": "elasticsearch",
            "Status": "Up 15 hours"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Something in the below format.
MachineName | ImageList | NameList | StatusList

I have managed to display data from below json:

```
 {"parsedBody": [{

            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Names": "mysql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        },
        {
            "Image": "kafka:latest",
            "Names": "kafka",
            "Status": "Up 15 hours"
        },
        {
            "Image": "postgresql:latest",
            "Names": "postgresql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        }
    ]
   }
```

Below is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class DockerProcess extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        d_processes: { "parsedBody": [{ "Image": "placeholder_image", "Names": "placeholder_name" }] }
    };
}
handleButtonClick = () => {
    axios.get("/getDockerProcesses").then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.setState({
            d_processes: response.data
        });
    });
};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Get Docker Processes</button>
            <ul>
                {this.state.d_processes.parsedBody.map((item, i) => {
                    return <li key={i}>{item.Names}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default DockerProcess;
```

Currently, I know the json key which is 'parsedBody' but if you see the first json body that I ve mentioned here, that is what I want to achieve and in there, the keys are different i.e. machine names like machine1, machine2, etc.

I am a newbie to frontend development so a few tips would help. Thanks.

Comment: You may use "machine" concatenated with index.

Comment: Can You post a code that you've managed to display. I will try to help you based on that

Comment: @AbdulhakimZeinu. I've posted that in the question.Thanks.

Comment: @SowmiyaP 'machine1' is just a sample. The actual names are quite different.

Comment: Could you please give a complete code. I will try to solve

Comment: @SowmiyaP the above is the complete code. On click of the button, the express endpoint 'getDockerProcesses' is called which currently gives the response as the second json body that I've posted and shows as a list on the UI. I need to render the first json instead now.

Comment: Please give clear info about your pblm. I couldn't able to understand. please give info  Whats you input and output . You have multiple objects in response data array and  you wish to rename those object key names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have modified your JSON array by removing the machine name. But still there is a way to differentiate between machiness.

```
    let arr = [
     [
        {    
            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Names": "mysql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        },
        {
            "Image": "kafka:latest",
            "Names": "kafka",
            "Status": "Up 15 hours"
        },
        {
            "Image": "postgresql:latest",
            "Names": "postgresql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "Image": "mysql:latest",
            "Names": "mysql",
            "Status": "Restarting (1) 18 seconds ago"
        },
        {
            "Image": "elasticsearch:latest",
            "Names": "elasticsearch",
            "Status": "Up 15 hours"
        }
    ]    
]
```

Then here is how to iterate through it to display every item

```
   <ul>
      { 
        arr.map((items, i) => {      
          return <div>{ 
            items.map((item, i) => {
              return <li key={i}>{item.Names+",  "+ item.Image}</li>
            })  }
             <h4>Next machine</h4></div>
         })
      }
   </ul>
```

you can see on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wave-unwmf?file=/src/App.js) how the output behaves

Comment: Thank so much for this. I've used your solution plus I've updated the json structure such that there is a key called 'machine' in every object in the json with the value as the actual machine name and then another key called 'processes' with the list of processes. I ve achieved what I wanted. Thanks again.